# Select value out of an array in Ruby

Tags: ruby

Please note - this post is being used as a class example, please do not down vote for asking such an obvious question

I am trying to pull out just the fourth value from this array.  Below you can see the few ways I've tried to do this.  Could anyone please suggest a method that will accomplish this?

```
    # creating the array
    array = [1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

    # attempted using an index value, which returned 7 instead 6
    array[4]
    7

    # attempted using pop method, which returned the array [6, 7, 8, 9]
    array.pop(4)
    [6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Comment: Have you thoroughly searched for an answer before asking your question? Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found (on this site or elsewhere) and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and above all, it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!

Comment: My original post had this as the first sentence: Please note - this post is being used as a class example, please do not down vote for asking such an obvious question.

Big thanks to the friendly Dave Newton for deleting that line.

Comment: Welcome to SO!  With 5 downvotes so far, you probably want to hide under a rock.  Don't be discouraged, and don't forsake SO.  People here really want to help, they just don't like seeing questions that suggest the asker hasn't done his or her homework.

Comment: Dave removed that line for a good reason -- it's not necessary, nor will it make any difference really. Good questions get up-votes, bad questions get downvotes. If anything, the first sentence was like a red-flag in the face of a bull. So, since Dave, who knows the site and how it works well, deleted it, WHY did you add it back? Are you trying to collect downvotes?

Answer (score 8):

Ruby array indexing is `0` based.

```
array = [1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
array[3] # => 6
```

[Read the docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html):

> Array indexing starts at 0, as in C or Java. A negative index is assumed to be relative to the end of the array---that is, an index of -1 indicates the last element of the array, -2 is the next to last element in the array, and so on.

Answer (score 2):

In order to get to the value you need you have to do this:

```
array[3]
```

Ruby started indexing at 0, so you need to subtract 1 from the actual value.